# Анимация отображения текста

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я затерялся в догадках. Я не знаю как это назвать и как искать. Дело в том что я хотел бы найти плагин на js/jq для определенной анимации для отображения текста. Тоесть как будет происходить процесс? Как в крутых фильмах где текст последовательно генерируется. Каждый символ изначально отображается как случайный заглавный другой символ английского алфавита и постепенно они превращаются в нужное слово.

Я нашел один пример: https://youtu.be/mxf6XWz3MgY?t=8m52s (на 8:53).

В общем конечно я мог бы сделать скрипт, но лично я с своим нулевым опытом убью в него много времени, так что наличие подобной библиотеки было бы крайне удобным.

Надеюсь это понятно объяснил..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот что-то похожее нашёл, за 5мин в google: [Shuffle Letters Effect](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/shuffle-letters-effect-jquery/)
[Демо](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2011/09/shuffle-letters-effect-jquery/)

Comment: Спасибо, теперь есть куда копать.

Answer (score 0):

С помощью ответа от предыдущего человека я нашел практически копию. Немного редактирования и у меня в руках чистый скрипт.

[Демо](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/4a0zwfcq/3/)

```
/**
 * @name        Shuffle Letters
 * @author      Martin Angelov
 * @version     1.0
 * @url         http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/shuffle-letters-effect-jquery/
 * @license     MIT License
 */

(function ($) {

    $.fn.shuffleLetters = function (prop) {

        var options = $.extend({
            "step": 8, // How many times should the letters be changed
            "fps": 25, // Frames Per Second
            "text": "", // Use this text instead of the contents
            "callback": function () {} // Run once the animation is complete
        }, prop)

        return this.each(function () {
            var el = $(this),
                str = "";

            // Preventing parallel animations using a flag;
            if (el.data('animated')) {
                return true;
            }
            el.data('animated', true);

            if (options.text) {
                str = options.text.split('');
            } else {
                str = el.text().split('');
            }

            // The types array holds the type for each character;
            // Letters holds the positions of non-space characters;

            var types = [],
                letters = [];

            // Looping through all the chars of the string

            for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

                var ch = str[i];

                if (ch == " ") {
                    types[i] = "space";
                    continue;
                } else if (/[a-z]/.test(ch)) {
                    types[i] = "lowerLetter";
                } else if (/[A-Z]/.test(ch)) {
                    types[i] = "upperLetter";
                } else {
                    types[i] = "symbol";
                }

                letters.push(i);
            }

            el.html("");

            // Self executing named function expression:

            (function shuffle(start) {

                // This code is run options.fps times per second
                // and updates the contents of the page element

                var i,
                len = letters.length,
                    strCopy = str.slice(0); // Fresh copy of the string

                if (start > len) {

                    // The animation is complete. Updating the
                    // flag and triggering the callback;

                    el.data('animated', false);
                    options.callback(el);
                    return;
                }

                // All the work gets done here
                for (i = Math.max(start, 0); i < len; i++) {

                    // The start argument and options.step limit
                    // the characters we will be working on at once

                    if (i < start + options.step) {
                        // Generate a random character at thsi position
                        strCopy[letters[i]] = randomChar(types[letters[i]]);
                    } else {
                        strCopy[letters[i]] = "";
                    }
                }

                el.text(strCopy.join(""));

                setTimeout(function () {

                    shuffle(start + 1);

                }, 1000 / options.fps);

            })(-options.step);


        });
    };

    function randomChar(type) {
        var pool = "";

        if (type == "lowerLetter") {
            pool = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        } else if (type == "upperLetter") {
            pool = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        } else if (type == "symbol") {
            pool = ",.?/\\(^)![]{}*&^%$#'\"";
        }

        var arr = pool.split('');
        return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
    }

})(jQuery);


$(function () {
    var container = $("#container"),
        userText = $('#userText');

    // Shuffle the contents of container
    container.shuffleLetters();

    // Bind events
    userText.click(function () {
        userText.val("");
    }).bind('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            // The return key was pressed
            container.shuffleLetters({
                "text": userText.val()
            });
            userText.val("");
        }
    }).hide();

    // Leave a 4 second pause

    function last() {
        console.log(container);
        // Shuffle the container with custom text
        container.shuffleLetters({
            "text": "Test it for yourself!"
        });
        userText.val("type anything and hit return..").fadeIn();
    }

    var container = $("#container");

    container.shuffleLetters();

    function shuffle(text) {
        console.log(text);
        // Shuffle the container with custom text
        container.shuffleLetters({
            text: text
        });
    }

    var arr = ['TEXT 1', 'TEXT 2', 'TEXT 3', 'TEXT 4'];
    var i = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        shuffle(arr[i++ % arr.length]);
    }, 2000);
});
```